# How do i handle password storage for sign-in to the SMTP client in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-core, smtpclient, password-storage

I'm currently working on a ASP.NET Core application, where part of it is a 'EmailService' Now, it's only function is to send informative emails via. SMTP, using the clients own credentials however. And I'm quite uncertain as to how I should handle storage of these credentials, to enable SMTP, it needs:

- server address
- Port
- mail address
- password

all but the password, i suppose could be safely stored in the database, but how do I go about storing the password?

(The database is NOT stored on the same machine, if that makes any sort of a difference)

Comment: "using the clients own credentials" - you're trying to send email though an external server, on the client's behalf (or, put another way, you want to send an email using their email account)?

Comment: There are dozens of ways to do this, and many of them depend on what platform you are hosting your code. If you're in Azure for example, then use KeyVault. Other than that, this question is too opinion based really.

Comment: @TiesonT. Yes. The same way something like Dynamics NAV does it, basically.

Comment: @DavidG right, I'm merely looking for a 'not awful way' I can encrypt the credentials, sure, but still, I don't think that quite cuts it.

Comment: @user3801839 I'm not sure who or what "Dynamics NAV" is, but are you 100% sure that all of your clients can/will allow this? Gmail (and Google Email for Business), for instance, requires explicitly dialing down a bunch of security features to allow remote SMTP access, and not everyone is able or willing to do that.

Comment: @TiesonT. Microsoft's smaller sibling to AX. Anyhow, yes, they I believe they would and no, it's not mandatory, it's just a feature.

Comment: Simply, you want something where values are stored encrypted at rest. That could literally be *anything*, so you'll need to do your own research and make a choice. Like @DavidG suggested, you can use Azure KeyVault. That can actually be used whether or not your app actually lives  in Azure, as well. It's not free, but it's relatively cheap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated there are several ways of handling this.

The solution I picked was using .NET Core built in stuff from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection` by doing `.AddDataProtection()` on the service collection so it can be accessed through DI.

This is done in a controller by:

```
private IDataProtector myProtector;

public Mycontroller(IDataProtectionProvider provider)
{
    this.myProtector = provider.CreateProtector("myPurpose");

    var encryptedString = this.myProtector.Protect("somestring");

    var decryptedstring = this.myProtector.Unprotect(encryptedString);

}
```

It supports a lot of different key configuration, and I'd recommend using this with .NET Core.